# problemas com redirecionamento no .httacess

Tags: php, apache, php-7

O que que tem de **errado** neste **código**:

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteBase /crud/

  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/manutencao.php$ [NC]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.(jpe?g?|png|gif|css|js) [NC]
  RewriteRule .* manutencao.php [R=302,L]

</ifModule>
```

Tudo que eu preciso é que normalmente abra o index.php (***da raiz do site ( \ )***) para qualquer `link` solicitado na `url`,

E, se caso, o **.htaccess** receber uma chamada ao arquivo **manutencao.php** por ***redirecionamento***.

```
<?php

namespace CLASSES\UTIL;

class Constantes {

    static private $livre = true;   

    public function __construct($_util) {

        if (self::$livre == false) {
            header ("Location: manutencao.php");
            exit;
        }
        ...
```

Então, ao invés do **.htaccess** `redirecionar` para a **index.php** novamente 
por cauda da `regra`

```
  RewriteRule .* manutencao.php [R=302,L]
```

então ele permitirá que se abra **manutencao.php** com suas `imagens` e `css's`

Onde eu estou errando que não consigo descobrir de jeito nenhum?

---

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
  # LIGA O MOTOR DE REESCRITA (Rewrite)
  RewriteEngine on
  # BUSCA PELA BASE /crud/ NO HOST ACESSADO
  RewriteBase /crud/
  # FAZ UMA ESCESSÃO DE REDIRECIONAMENTO PARA A PÁGINA manutencao.php CASO O NAVEGADOR RECEBA ELA NA URL
  # PERCEBA O ! ANTES DO NOME DO ARQUIVO. ISSO DIZ AO .htaccess QUE O ARQUIVO EM QUESTÃO NÃO SEGUE A REGRA E ABRE NORMALMENTE
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/manutencao.php$ [NC]
  # FAZ UMA ESCESSÃO E LIBERA IMAGENS NESTA PAGINA
  # NOTE QUE PAR ESAS EXTENSÕES, O REDIRECIONAMENTO NÃO ACONTECE E DÁ ERRO 404 CASO A IMAGEM NÃO EXISTA
  # AS DEMAIS EXTENSÕES SÃO TODAS REENVIADAS PARA A INDEX
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.(jpe?g?|png|gif|css|js) [NC]
  # REENVIA QUALQUER ACESSO AO SITE PARA A PÁGINA index.php NO HOST INDICADO LIBERANDO AS EXCESSÕES ACIMA DESCRITAS
  RewriteRule .* index.php
</ifModule>
```